# Ubuntu 16.04.7 sshd won't accept 4096 bit public key authentication

Tags: openssh, key-authentication

[Ubuntu 16.04.7, OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.10, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016, updated today as part of this activity]

I'm trying to setup public key authentication for a new user I want to give access to, but whenever I use a 4096bit key, I get an error stating:

```
user@host: Permission denied (publickey).
```

I created the key using:

```
ssh-keygen \
  -f id_rsa_4096 \
  -t rsa \
  -b 4096 \
  -C 'The Key' \
  -o \
  -N ''
```

on both my local machine, MacOS, and on the server itself (via another account).  I have the `.ssh` folder permission @700 and `authorized_keys` file permission @600, with correct ownerships on both. Neither version works, however, when I switch to a 2048bit key, the user authenticates fine.

Has anyone else had this problem?  How can it be solved?

Comment: Suddenly it started working.  No idea why as I'm not aware of any time-outs of caching.